# Saving a struct array to an external file in c++

Tags: c++, struct, external

I have an assignment where I need to:

1. save the list that the user inputs to an external file.
2. load the info from the file previously saved.

I managed to write in the code for the 1st task, but since I have errors, I couldn't continue to the 2nd task. Please take a look and let me know what your thoughts are.

Comment: "*but since I have errors, I couldn't continue to the 2nd task.*" - Consider providing *what* error you actually get and on what line, as that might be useful in some way, by adding that into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I included the errors I am getting.

Comment: In line 42 change `animal` to `size`. Show definition of `pet` class.

Comment: Weird. My compiler is flipping smurf over the numbers at the beginning of each line.

Comment: `bool save(ofstream out, int current_size)` needs to be `bool save(ofstream &  out, int current_size)` you can't pass a stream by value.

Comment: *"let me know what your thoughts are."* -- that's not how SO works. Asking for open-ended feedback is off-topic. The expectation is that you ask a *specific* question. In this case, you should focus on your **first** error, reduce your code to the minimum needed to reproduce that error (meaning the same error message is produced, and it is still the first error), and ask either 1) why it is an error or 2) how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Error:

When you create an array, the name of the array is a pointer to the beginning of where the array is in memory. In line 42, you cannot compare an int with a pointer like that. Instead, I assume you want to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
```

Second Error:

In line 43, you are trying to input an std::ofstream object into a function. In order to do this, std::ofstream must be copy-able. ofstream has a deleted copy constructor, meaning that it cannot be copied and thus cannot be passed as an input to a function. Instead, you could simply create the ofstream object and  open the file within your pet::save function. Also, make sure you close the ofstream. As an example:

```
void pet::save()
{
   ofstream file;
   out.open("animal.txt");
   if (!out.is_open())
      cout << "Unable of open file." << endl;
   file << pet_info << endl;
   file.close();
}
```

You could also use a pointer to the ofstream as an input to your save function, since pointers can be copied (then use out->operator<<(pet_info) to input to the file). This would make it run faster, but this situation does not seem to prompt such optimization. The function prototype would look like

```
void pet::save(ofstream* file);
```

and you would pass &out as the input to the function.

Third Error:

You are trying to use the array called animal within your pet class. Since animal is an array of pets that is created outside of your pet class, the pet class does not have access to it (so animal was not declared in the scope of pet). I am guessing your pet class stores a string which contains a pet's information (which I call pet_info). Given that is true, you can call the above save function that I wrote for all of your pets in the animal array to save them to a file.

Fourth Error:

On line 109 of pet.cpp, it appears you are missing a semicolon. That could be why the bracket error is there, or you are just missing a bracket.

Comment: You can pass the ofstream by reference like you do in operator<<(ofstream & ... for example: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-170)